# How do I make dropdown roles in pycord?

Tags: pycord

As many may know, discord.py has stopped being maintained. As a result of this, I switched over to Pycord.

My question is:

How do I make the dropdown menu do roles?

I looked at the example on the [Github Example file for making dropdown menus in **Pycord**](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/blob/master/examples/views/dropdown.py), and I attempted to make a dropdown menu (successfully). However, this only sends a message when an option is selected from the menu. I want to use this menu for adding and removing roles. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Select(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label="role name", description="Add the Role_Name role"), #These are the labels
            discord.SelectOption(label="role name 2", description="Add role name role."),#^

        ]
        super().__init__(placeholder="Waiting for selection...", max_values=1, min_values=1, options=options)#what will be written waiting for a choise

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if self.values[0] == 'role name': #'role name'must be the same as the label u want the action to happen. Ex: if label name == hi, well uchange role name to hi here
            role = interaction.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID_HERE)#add ur role ID here
            await interaction.user.add_roles(role)#Basically if the interaction happen, itll add the role role^ to the user
        elif self.values[0] == 'role name 2':
            rolee = interaction.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID_HERE)#same as up
            await interaction.user.add_roles(rolee)


class SelectView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.add_item(Select())

@client.command()
async def droproles(ctx):
    select = SelectView(timeout=None)
    await ctx.send("Choose ur role here", view=select)
```

This is the code. If there is an error tell me, i didnt test it, but it should work. If u dont understand something, tell me. U need to understand to be able to re do it sometime